# Understanding Wordpress(framework?) Web Development

Tags: theme-development

I have come across a wonderful portfolio website https://dogstudio.co/ while I was looking for examples of design. Upon exploring the source-code, it was apparent that this was a wordpress website after all.

What I don't understand is how and why does it not have the typical wordpress directory hierarchy. For example, this is the URL to their CSS file, https://dogstudio.co/app/themes/portfolio-2018/static/css/main.css.

A typical wordpress website would have something like this, https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme_name/style.css (the **wp-content** and **wp-** prefixed directories) as a general rule of thumb for making wordpress themes.

So was it made using a framework? I really need to understand this.

Comment: It does not seems to be a wp site for me, however default wp directories can be changed, check out this: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/renaming-wordpress-wp-content-folder/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That site probably uses the Roots Bedrock framework, which moves the theme/plugin folders around into an `app` subfolder. This is mainly due to the preference of that framework though, rather than for any structural benefit.

It's also possible they use standard WordPress but have renamed `wp-content` using constants in `wp-config.php` , e.g.

```php
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://example.com/app');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/example.com/public_html/app/');
```

### Why Change the wp-content directory location?

If you want to use a git submodule to install WordPress, or a package manager such as `composer`, having WordPress in a subfolder on its own makes it easier to update and install.

This necessitates moving `wp-content` out of that folder though to avoid nested folders. E.g `composer` updates packages by deleting them and installing the new version, which would destroy all uploaded files, plugins, and themes.

So instead, you might have a folder structure like this:

```
 - wordpress ( sometimes wp )
 - wp-content
   - themes
   - plugins
   - etc..
 - wp-config.php
 - index.php
```

Such a setup requires more steps to set up than a normal WordPress install however, and isn't well suited for most use cases and hosts. If you're using the auto-updater to keep WordPress up to date and don't use a site-wide version control, or use WP CLI to update WordPress, then you won't see many benefits by moving to this setup.

As for why Bedrock does it that way, the answer is simple, the maintainers prefer those folder names and organisation. Other than that Bedrock provides a local environment, but not much else. It's a boilerplate for setting up WordPress. For more info or if you have questions about Bedrock, you should visit https://roots.io/bedrock/ and ask in their community

Comment: and this has nothing to do with performance or page load times or any of the "necessary" metrics? I can still have the page transitions and everything else just as smooth and fast using the "normal" WP way, right?

Comment: Indeed, it has no impact on performance or metrics, or the way you build your site. TLDR the bedrock people prefer this folder layout, it's purely a personal preference not a technical advantage. Everything works the same way. Some very  poorly built plugins that hardcode `wp-content` might break though, but that's due to poor coding

Comment: Generally, WP "frameworks" focus on enabling people to do things that might be beyond their current skills, or save development time. There isn't a lot of room to impact performance etc, since the parts that determine the performance of the site are the parts determined by you. Any framework can be used to make an awfully performing site if you decide you want to make a HTTP request on every page load, or fetch 1000 posts per page, or any of the others, so don't pursue frameworks in hopes of performance gains

Answer (score 0):

You can store WordPress static assets anywhere, even on a CDN completely separate from the server hosting your website.  Most likely what they're doing here are utilizing server rewrites that point /app/themes -> /wp-content/themes.

It's also possible to change the location of the wp-content/themes path completely using the `register_theme_directory(ABSPATH . 'app/themes')` function.

If you're asking why they did this, it could be as simple as code aesthetics or as complex as a customized multisite installation with once centralized WordPress codebase.